# Jittering location in animation

Tags: animation

I'm trying to jitter an object's location during an animation, and be able to control the *strength* of the hitter. I tried keyframing the strength of a noise f-curve modifier, which doesn't work:

```
Failed to resolve path to property, try manually specifying this using a Keying Set instead
```

Is there a good way to jitter the location of an object, and change the strength of the jitter throughout the animation?

Comment: can switch to drivers ?it would be easier

Comment: Not sure how to do that.. Which driver var could I use to jitter the location?

Comment: you have the same modifiers in the drivers as for F-curve and on top of that you can scripted expression , you can also have the same f-curve for an empty then use the empty loc as driver for the object

Comment: I don't think that allows me to change the intensity of the noise jitter throughout the animation though, does it?

Comment: I updated the question to make less of an assumption about how to achieve the animation technique..

Comment: I see your trying to do meta-animation :) From my understanding, this is not possible since these buttons don't have RNA paths, because they're not controlled by _Python_, but rather _C++_. This, in the current system, means these values cannot be animated in any way; thus, the only way to do this, would be using something other than F-Curves - probably a script which animates the "jitter" with keyframes, which, however, seems rather inefficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this test scene:

- the empty has the original animation
- the cube copies the empty animation and adds some random value
- the amplitude of the random value is controlled by cube property :

this is the driver of the X_loc of the cube :

[image]

this is the animation while changing the cube property :

[image]

Comment: @ajwood you can keyframe the cube property ,change the noise function [check this page](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Animation/Basics/Drivers#Driver_Namespace)