# How Do I Create Random Animated Transformations?

Tags: eevee-render-engine, transforms

I'm trying to make each individual cube increase in height, and then decrease, and then increase (so it's basically bobbing up and down slowly), but each cube should be randomly vertically transformed, so they are all different sizes from each other.

[Video similar to what I want](https://www.storyblocks.com/video/stock/white-3d-glossy-plastic-cubes-smoothly-going-up-and-down-abstract-technology-background-clip-dvqsrir)

I am using Eevee for fast render times and because I don't need complex lighting setups.

Cubes and current node setup (just material and colors for now) below.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You can use a driver or a script. The answers to this question will probably help you:
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33962/how-do-i-create-a-driver-with-a-random-value-and-apply-that-driver-to-multiple-o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of Randomize transform. First, make sure all your Cubes are separate objects that have their respective origins at their centers. Select all your objects (in object mode) and select "Randomize Transform" from the Object menu.

[image: Rand1]

Keyframe your object at 0 transformation - Press <kbd>I</kbd> and pick "Location and Scale". Make sure to do this at the *Beginning* **AND** the *End* of your animation first (if you want the position to reset) because each time you use the Randomize Transform operation, it "adds" the last values you set to what's currently there. TLDR - keyframe your first and last frame at 0 location and scale transforms first.

[image: Rand2]

Then, you can pick a spot in the middle, go crazy on the Z-location and Z-scale transforms, and keyframe that too.

[image: Rand3]

The end result looks like this:

[image: Rand4]

Here's a better example using some more conservative values for the transforms (closer to your example). The reflections are from an HDRI I used - I should have picked a different one - in the gif they look kind of strange.

[image: Rot5]

Comment: oh god this is great, I was ready to downgrade my blender version just so I could install Animation Nodes. TYSM

Comment: I noticed that they all move uniformly relative to each other, is it possible to randomize each individual seed?

Comment: If you mean you want some of them to move at different "speeds" relative to each other, I don't know of any way to do it automatically (doesn't mean it doesn't exist - I'm just not aware of it). I think if you wanted something like that, you might have so select some of the cubes in "batches" and keyframe them separately with a different seed.